# How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11, openjfx

I have a JavaFX (JDK 8) desktop business application, which uses Java Web Start for deployment.  Users have Java 8 installed, and they simply go to the URL (a public URL on my AWS Linux server) and the application downloads / starts (using Web Start).  I can easily update the application, too, by deploying new JARs to the server.  Everything works well.

However, Oracle has discontinued Web Start with Java 11, and in their “Java Client Roadmap Update” white paper, March 2018, they recommend bundling a JRE with the application (“The notion of an application being distributed separately from a standalone JRE is, therefore, quickly fading.”).  I cannot rely on my users to stay at Java 8 for Web Start, and even if they do remain at 8, Oracle requires a license to continue using Java 8 (which I do not have, can be very costly, and I’d prefer anyways to move with the community towards JavaFX 11 and OpenJDK).

I would like to migrate to JavaFX 11.  I have followed OpenJFX’s “Getting Started with JavaFX11” (https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), using OpenJDK 11.0.1 with Gluon’s JavaFX SDK 11.0.1 (on Netbeans 10vc2), and have been able to get the sample applications to run (and appears to me I should be able to port my JavaFX 8 code to JavaFX 11, quite easily).

However, this is where I am stuck for direction. How do I bundle this with the JRE and deploy this to my end-users (and provide application updates)?  Is there an easy way out there (or even a hard way, with some direction/guides)?

I can spend hundreds of hours writing expressive, rich, and useful desktop business applications in JavaFX 11, but what do I do then?

Are the deployment toolkits, like JWrapper, InstallAnywhere, etc, suited to this new era of Java 11?  Does Gluon/openjfx.io perhaps have a recommendation or guide I missed?  I cannot seem to find any recommendations or guides from reputable sources, for how us developers, who focus on writing the front-end code, are to deploy the applications.

Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: IMO, the deployment view of applications has been left really less documented and there have been significant changes in terms of building and deploying the applications with Java11+. You can possibly look at `jlink` and creating runtime images with it. But for the community, you would have to post it step by step as you give it a try and maybe you could stitch a solution then.

Comment: Using the [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) tool that's included with the JDK you can create a self-contained, customized JRE with only the parts that your app needs. I guess that's what Oracle thinks you should use now instead of Web Start.

Comment: As of December 1, 2018, there is a posting with more information on this: medium.com/@adam_carroll/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8

Comment: Just curious how large the executable ends up being with this new approach?

Comment: Follow [these tutorials](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) found at the [new home for JavaFX](https://openjfx.io) after having [been spun out](https://gluonhq.com/gluon-and-javafx/) of Oracle to [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com).

Comment: @BasilBourque THANK YOU!!!!! This actually worked for me and I was having issues getting the executable JAR to run and this solved it.

Answer (score 44):

The way it works now is, you convert your program to a module, then “link” it to all the other modules it requires.

The result of this linking process is what’s known as an image.  An image is actually a file tree, which includes a `bin` directory with one or more ready-to-run executables.  This tree is what you distribute, typically as a zip or tar.gz.

The steps are:

1. Create a module-info.java
2. Compile with a module path instead of a classpath
3. Create a jar from classes, as usual
4. Convert jar to a jmod with the JDK’s `jmod` tool
5. Link that jmod, and the modules on which it depends, into an image

## Writing a module descriptor

The first step is to turn the application into a module.  Minimally, this requires creating a `module-info.java` at the top of your source tree (that is, in the empty package).  Every module has a name, which is often the same as a package name but doesn’t have to be.  So, your module-info.java might look like this:

```
module com.mcs75.businessapp {
    exports com.mcs75.desktop.businessapp;

    requires java.logging;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
}
```

## Building

When you build, you don’t specify a classpath at all.  Instead, you specify a module path.

A module path is a list of directories, not files.  Each directory contains, not surprisingly, modules.  The `jmods` directory of the JDK is included implicitly.  All you need to include is directories containing the non-JDK modules you need.  In your case, that at least means Gluon’s JavaFX:

```
javac -Xlint -g -d build/classes --module-path /opt/gluon-javafx/lib \
    src/java/com/mcs75/desktop/businessapp/*.java
```

Then you create a jar the usual way:

```
jar -c -f build/mybusinessapp.jar -C build/classes .
```

A jar file with a module-info.class in it is considered a modular jar.

## Making a jmod

Creating a jmod is usually a simple process:

```
mkdir build/modules
jmod create --class-path build/mybusinessapp.jar \
    --main-class com.mcs75.desktop.businessapp.BusinessApplication \
    build/modules/mybusinessapp.jmod
```

## Linking

Finally, you use the JDK’s `jlink` command to assemble everything:

```
jlink --output build/image \
    --module-path build/modules:/opt/gluon-javafx/lib \
    --add-modules com.mcs75.businessapp \
    --launcher MyBusinessApp=com.mcs75.businessapp
```

`jlink` creates a minimal JRE, which contains only the modules you explicitly add (and the modules those explicit modules require).  `--add-modules` is the required option that specifies what to add.

As with other JDK tools, `--module-path` specifies directories containing modules.

The `--launcher` option causes the final image tree to have an additional executable script in its `bin` directory with the given name (the part before the equals).  So, `MyBusinessApp=com.mcs75.businessapp` means “create an executable named MyBusinessApp, which executes the module com.mcs75.businessapp.”

Because the `jmod create` command included a `--main-class` option, Java will know what to execute, just like declaring a Main-Class attribute in a manifest.  It is also possible to explicitly declare a class to execute in the `--launcher` option if desired.

## Distributing

What you will want to distribute is a zip or tar.gz of the entire image file tree.  The executable that the user should run is in the image’s `bin` directory.  Of course, you are free to add your own executables.  You are also free to place this into any kind of installer, as long as the image tree’s structure is preserved.

<del>A future JDK will have a [packaging tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) for creating full-fledged native installers.</del>  As of Java 14, the JDK has a [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) tool which can create native installers.  For example:

```
jpackage -n MyBusinessApp --runtime-image build/image \
    -m com.mcs75.businessapp/com.mcs75.desktop.businessapp.BusinessApplication
```

`-n` specifies the name of the program.  `--runtime-image` specifies the location of the existing jlink’d image.  `-m` is the module and class within the jlink’d image to execute, much like the portion after the `=` in jlink’s `--launcher` option.

## Cross-building

Since the image includes native binaries, you will need to create an image for each platform.  Obviously, one option is to build the image on a Linux system, and again on a Windows system, and again on a Mac, etc.

But you can also use `jmod` and `jlink` to create images for other platforms, regardless of where you’re building.

There’s only a few additional steps needed.  First, you will need the JDKs for those other platforms.  Download them as archives (zip or tar.gz), not installers, and unpack them to directories of your choice.

Each JDK defines a *platform* string.  This is normally of the form <os>-<arch>.  The platform is a property of the `java.base` module; you can see any JDK’s platform by examining that module:

```
jmod describe path-to-foreign-jdk/jmods/java.base.jmod | grep '^platform'
```

Pass that platform string to your jmod command using the `--target-platform` option:

```
mkdir build/modules
jmod create --target-platform windows-amd64 \
    --class-path build/mybusinessapp.jar \
    --main-class com.mcs75.desktop.businessapp.BusinessApplication \
    build/modules/mybusinessapp.jmod
```

Finally, when linking, you want to explicitly include the other JDK’s `jmods` directory, so jlink won’t implicitly include its own JDK’s modules:

```
jlink --output build/image \
    --module-path path-to-foreign-jdk/jmods:build/modules:/opt/gluon-javafx-windows/lib \
    --add-modules com.mcs75.businessapp \
    --launcher MyBusinessApp=com.mcs75.businessapp
```

Comment: As of December 1, 2018, there is a posting with more information on this: https://medium.com/@adam_carroll/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8

Comment: How do you best integrate these steps in Maven?

Comment: @IggyBlob I don’t use Maven, so I don’t know.  For what it’s worth, I searched for “maven goal jlink” and came up with https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/usage.html.

Comment: When using jlink while building for another platform, does one have to point to that platform's javafx jmods?

Comment: @Icedude_907 Yes.

Comment: @VGR jlink seems to be good only if all of your dependencies have module-info in their jar files...Otherwise, it won't make a custom run-time.  Which means, I went back to creating a non-modular app in which a user has to install a JDK 12 on their machine...  However, even NetBeans has huge issues creating runnable jars (it won't even put your dependency jars into a "lib" folder for you, like in JDK8)

Comment: @trilogy You are correct;  only named modules may comprise a jlink’d application.  You can make each .jar a module.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222226/how-to-inject-module-declaration-into-jar.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier use an IDE, I use Intellij Idea; build automation, I use gradle; and jlink plugin, I use the badass Jlink plugin - https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/#jpackageImage. You can then easily use jlink and jpackage. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

While other answers have a lot of details on how to do this manually, it's also possible to use a build tool plugin, e.g., for Maven.

Using the [JavaPackager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager) Maven plugin, for example, simply adding something like this in your POM might already be enough:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.fvarrui</groupId>
    <artifactId>javapackager</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                <bundleJre>true</bundleJre>
                <platform>windows</platform>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running `mvn package` will generate a directory inside "target" that contains the EXE, a "jre" directory and a "libs" directory. The plugin can also generate an installer file.

Obviously, for different platforms you need to adjust the config, but I tested this on Windows with JDK 16 and 17, and it seems to work fine.