# Ant tasks definitions OpenJDK 11 JavaFX SDK 11 Eclipse 2018-12

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant

I am trying to build a JavaFX application using Ant in Eclipse 2018-12. To do this, Ant tasks definitions are required, see point 10.3 at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html . Before updating to OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11 the definitions where loaded from antlib.xml and ant-javafx.jar .Now these two files are no longer available, and jfxrt.jar as well.
does somebody know what shall I do?

Here are the relevant rows of build.xml that was working previusly:

```
<project name="myProj" default="do-deploy" xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To address these requirements previously, a packaging tool called
>   javapackager was distributed with Oracle’s JDK 8. However, it was
>   removed from Oracle’s JDK 11 as part of the removal of JavaFX.

The packager was removed from Java 11. See [JEP 343: Packaging Tool](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343)

It seems this is the only way for Java 11+. [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre)