# How to deploy JavaFX12 app to multiple platforms with same code base

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jlink, jmod

I followed the instructions to create a "Modular IDE" Project with NetBeans 11 on Windows 10:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans

I end up creating a project that looks like this:

[image]

I then ran "Clean and Build" (set up jlink+jmod in nebeans) and  I get a Windows distribution folder that contains self-running java runtime with all of the dependencies included (around 90 Megs)

[image]

Which I can run either through command prompt "HelloFX" or double clicking on "HelloFX.bat"

[image]

This is all fine and good. However, my "HelloFX Project" in netbeans is using the Windows JavaFX libraries and Windows Jmods libraries. Which means this process will work if I want to deploy to Windows machines, but not to a Mac. Would I have to create a brand new project for the Mac? Is there no way that I am able to click a button to "Clean and Build for Mac" and "Clean and Build for Windows"? Or is there a way to use the same code base? I basically want to bring a JavaFX 8 project code base into this new structure. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: See the “Cross-building” section at the end of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453519/1831987 … though I don’t know offhand how to integrate this into a Netbeans project, other than manually altering that project’s build.xml.

Comment: This is not a matter of the code base, it is a matter of the machine you are doing the build on. If you transfer your code base from windows to a Mac for example, then you can do a build for the Mac on this machine with the same code base. You will have to test your build on each target platform anyway before you can deliver it.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I suppose this works if I can get it easily working with NetBeans...

Comment: @mipa With Java 8 I didn't need to test for the Mac as others would test for me. But I see your point. Just means I'll have to ask for a Mac now!