# How to package OpenJDK with a Jar file?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

OpenJDK11 is just a zip file. So is there a way I can include openjdk in a file with with a jar file so that I can send a program to someone and they can run it? In other words, even if they have a different version of java on their machine, when they run the code I give them, it will use the java 11 files I put with it.

*Docker isn't an option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre.

Answer (score 2):

OpenJDK11 is *not* just a zip file. Each platform has a different variant, for example.

[jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) is the tool (introduced with jdk9, so you're good to go) that can make ready to go apps that include a shaken-down JRE. You'll need to run it for every platform you want to target.