# Create .exe from JAR including JRE with openJDK11

Tags: java, launch4j, netbeans-11, openjdk-11

I am trying to make a `.exe` without result, I am using OpenJDK 11 and netbeans11, first I tried to do it using Package as >> All Artifacts but I am getting just this error I tried to fix it with no result finally `nbproject\build-native.xml:519: typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]`
I add the jar JAVAFX as libraries but it does not work any way (My project is not a JavaFX project I do not understand why I am getting this error).
So I passed to the next solution to make the `.exe`, Launch4j but I get an executable that I can not launch without JRE 11 installed in the system but I need to include the JRE inside the `.exe`, the user does not have to install JRE 11 to open the `.exe`.
Please if you have any solution I will be gracefull.

cordially

`nbproject\build-native.xml:519: typedef class com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]`

Comment: Java Deployment tools were [removed as of Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077).  It appears the [JavaFX Ant tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/javafx-ant-tasks.htm#JSDPG177) were part of the deployment tools.  One option is to [jlink your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre) instead.

Comment: I succeeded to make the .exe of myapp  using JLaunch4j finaly but to make it work I have to put in the same dir of the .exe the dir of JRE. 
It's not practical for the user, if i move the myapp.exe from the dir nothing works :( , I will try your solution but I don't want to have the dir of lib and JRE near to myapp.exe to be able to launch it ....