# Convert Jar file to standalone OSX application

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, jar

Is there a way to convert a Java application (Jar file) into a standalone Mac application that can run on OSX without needing Java to be installed?

(Please note that the key part of this question is "standalone", I have seen many many post creating Jar files that require Java to be installed and they have not solved my issue.)

I use Netbeans and am running the newest JDK and am open to third party apps or any functions that Netbeans/Oracle may provide. Through Netbeans I have been able to package my Jar as a standalone windows (.exe) file so I assume it must be possible for OSX as well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! Unfortunate that Native Packaging is not as simple as it used to be; the scale of my project does not quite merit the significant time commitment it seems to require to export.