# Error: Could not find or load main class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, javafx, jar, classpath, executable-jar

I'm trying to create an Exe file for my JavaFX project, after building the artifacts I try to run the jar by `java -jar name.jar` and I get the error at the title.

I was following the answer here [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)  but nothing helped.

Then i tried to do this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuFOCEHh8Zg&feature=youtu.be and it still happened.

In the project i use `mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar` , `mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar` , `jfoenix-9.0.10.jar` and of course the JavaFx lib.

The values of CLASSPATH in the system variable are : [CLASSPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRAtZ.png)

The libs at the project: [libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18nSg.png)

MANIFEST:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MainPackage.Main
Class-Path: C:\Users\amttr\Desktop\pol\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\* C:\Users\amttr\Desktop\pol\lib\*
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using the `-jar` option, then the setting of CLASSPATH is irrelevant.  The only thing that affects the classpath for an executable JAR is the setting in the JAR file manifest.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.

Comment: (P.S. I'm not watch a video.  For a start, it doesn't tell us what you *actually* did.  Likewise, telling us that you "followed" some other Q&A doesn't tell you what you actually did either.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I read the doc 3 times and still couldn't understand what should be the value of class-path at manifest depending on my libs. @StephenC

Comment: You will need to list in the jar manifest class-path the relative path to the library jars you've used.  Depending on the version of JRE you are using, you may need to make adjustments so the JavaFX modules are visible as well.  You also haven't provided the full  output from attempting to run your program.

Comment: Does name.jar have a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` entry in it?  Does that entry’s content contain a `Main-Class` line?

Comment: @VGR Yes there is a `Main-Class` line with the correct class.
And `Class-Path: C:\Users\amttr\Desktop\pol\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\* C:\Users\amttr\Desktop\pol\lib\*`

Comment: @swpalmer What kind of adjustments i have to do ?
and the full output: `Error: Could not find or load main class MainPackage.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainPackage.Main`

Comment: Your Class-Path is invalid.  The entries in a manifest Class-Path are not identical to the entries that would be allowed in a `-cp` argument.  They must be relative URLs, which means they must not start with `C:` and they must use forward slashes (`/`) to separate directory names.  And they must point to actual .jar files;  the convenience of ending with `*` is not permitted here.  See [the Class-Path section of the jar specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute).

Comment: @VGR So you mean that I have to add every jar that I used separately include the JavaFx jars?
Do you have any sample for correct MANIFEST?

Comment: Yes.  That jar specification link has some examples.  Another option is [creating a deployable application image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre/53453519#53453519), if you’re using Java 9 or later.

Comment: @VGR Hi, after some tests i found out that the `mssql` jar makes the trouble (While the Class-Path is empty).  Any idea for including this jar as well without getting an error?