# Javafx Web 11 - Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java-11, javafx-11, javafx-webview

My application uses Java Fx Web to display html pages, the problem is that this error appears only when I run the .jar directly because when I run it from my ide (eclipse) it runs without problems. Does anyone have any idea what this is about?
I am using AdoptOpenJdk11. I have also tested it on my colleague's computer and it also doesn't work.

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:241)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:257)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.window.main.menu.GameMenuPanel.<init>(GameMenuPanel.java:62)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.states.LobbyConnectionState.enable(LobbyConnectionState.java:12)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.ClientApplication.loadComponents(ClientApplication.java:115)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.ClientApplication.lambda$initializate$0(ClientApplication.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.NetworkConnection.lambda$login$0(NetworkConnection.java:124)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.PacketResponse.lambda$whenComplete$0(PacketResponse.java:30)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.PacketResponse.complete(PacketResponse.java:24)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.request.PacketRequestLogin.onClientReceive(PacketRequestLogin.java:43)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.callback.PacketCallbackRequester.onReceive(PacketCallbackRequester.java:33)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.NetworkConnection.execute(NetworkConnection.java:94)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
```

Width -Dprism.verbose=true:

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:241)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:257)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.window.main.menu.GameMenuPanel.<init>(GameMenuPanel.java:62)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.states.LobbyConnectionState.enable(LobbyConnectionState.java:12)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.ClientApplication.loadComponents(ClientApplication.java:115)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.ClientApplication.lambda$initializate$0(ClientApplication.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.NetworkConnection.lambda$login$0(NetworkConnection.java:124)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.PacketResponse.lambda$whenComplete$0(PacketResponse.java:30)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.PacketResponse.complete(PacketResponse.java:24)
        at com.rubicon.game.core.network.packets.request.PacketRequestLogin.onClientReceive(PacketRequestLogin.java:43)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.callback.PacketCallbackRequester.onReceive(PacketCallbackRequester.java:33)
        at com.rubicon.game.client.network.NetworkConnection.execute(NetworkConnection.java:94)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
```

And in the line 62 im only creating a JFXPanel Object....
[JFXPanel Object Creation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTOlg.png)

Maven Dependencies? (Maybe need more? Maybe need another version?)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any additional necessary information just ask!

Solved! (MinimizeZar problem in maven)

Comment: How are you building the JAR?

Comment: With Maven! Pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/GVz845ph @Slaw

Comment: It's for a different error, but perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791?) can help you. You may also want to check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453519/6395627).

Comment: The problem is that I am not using the "Application" class because my app does other things as well... :/ Something also appears when it is being compiled, can something like "Minimizing Jar" be for this reason? @Slaw

Comment: In my experience, the error you're getting means JavaFX is present but the native code is missing. So if you're stripping things from the final JAR then that can indeed be the cause of the problem. Both `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.web` have corresponding native code. Make sure they're in your final JAR.

Comment: I'm also not sure how "Minimizing Jar" works, but make sure it isn't removing essential Java code as well. For instance, it looks like JavaFX uses reflection to load the needed pipeline and if the plugin doesn't recognize that it could be erroneously removing code it incorrectly thinks is not being used.

Comment: Aaaaaaaa thats it man!! Minimizing Jar things!

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228380/336557

Answer (score 5):

If someone comes here to get help about this error, add this line to your pom

```
<classifier>mac</classifier>
```

depending on your target platform : mac , linux, win

So the block becomes like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>17</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Anyone know how this would work for Gradle?

Comment: @ChristopherAllen yes, add it to the end of your implementation line: "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17:mac"

Comment: Adding a classifier is unnecessary for most builds and the `mac` classifier is incorrect for M processor (non-intel) macs.  Also, non-intel Macs require a more recent JavaFX version to work correctly, e.g. 19+.