# JavaFX Installation Issues: Error initializing QuantumRenderer

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I've been trying to install JavaFX for the last couple of hours, and I'm using VSCode. I'm trying to run a simple program, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:254)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:264)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:276)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        ... 5 more
```

I'd really appreciate some help :)

I'm using Java 15, I'm on MacOS Big Sur, and I downloaded JavaFX 17 from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/.

Comment: I'm using Java 15, I'm on MacOS Big Sur, and I downloaded the JavaFX from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/.

Comment: could take a look at this link? The comments would be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/q/68164297/16034206

Comment: I installed JavaFX 17.

Comment: JavaFX 17 is early-access. The current latest release if JavaFX 16. Make sure you downloaded the SDK for your operating system. JavaFX relies on platform-specific native code.

Comment: I'm positive I downloaded the correct SDK, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Did you add all jars in the folder `openjfx-17-ea+13_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17\lib` to **referenced libraries** in VS Code? How did you compile and run the program? I'm using windows and I download javafx17, the simple program could be executed successfully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong JavaFX runtime downloaded. I had downloaded the x64 SDK instead of the AArch64 SDK.

Comment: Ha! I'm on macOS Big Sur as well (11.6). Thanks, this ended up being my problem, but I had the reverse (needed x64 for my Intel MacBook Pro but had downloaded the AArch64 release). Note that I also needed to grant permission to maybe 5 or so dylibs (e.g. libprism_es2.dylib, libprism_sw.dylib, others) via System Preferences before I could run the app, because the Finder reported ""libprism_es2.dylib" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.": https://macresearch.org/fix-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-software/

Answer (score 1):

After downloading javafx17 and extracting them, i copy all jars in the folder `\javafx-sdk-17\lib` to **Referenced Libraries** in VS Code. Then i can compile and run `HelloFX.java` successfully with the following commands:

**Compile:**

```
javac --module-path path/to/javafx17/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

**Run:**

```
java --module-path path/to/javafx/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I've tried adding those commands in vmArgs in launch.json, and I've run them manually, but it gives me the same error message.