# Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, macos, gradle, javafx

I am currently working on a project for University in Java.
In the template for the project we already have a lot of Classes and configurations given. However, if I try to run the code, my build fails and it gives me the following error Message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

on top of that, I get the following warning:

```
Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4bde3f8a'
```

I feel like it has something to do with the gradle configuration, so I include my build.gradle (That I was given by my university):

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 17
version = '1.0.0'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "17"
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17:mac'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already google your problem? I also found the exception here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65737055/javafx-web-11-error-initializing-quantumrenderer-no-suitable-pipeline-found

Comment: Yes, I tried what was suggested in that Post (Adding org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17:mac to my implementation) However, that didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: start here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Here I have a working gradle.build file with kotlin as DSL: https://github.com/Jaster-Master/JavaFX-Gradle-Template/blob/main/build.gradle.kts - If this does not help you, there must be some other problem with a local javafx sdk on your device or something else. Which OS do you use?

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you that was the problem. I upgraded to version 19 and everything is running smoothly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use later versions

JavaFX support for [M1/M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon#M_series) Macs is unreliable in some JavaFX 17 distributions.

Instead, **use JavaFX 19 or greater**, same for the Java runtime. As of 2023-08, JavaFX ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/)) version 20 is current, with 21 planned for next month. See [*Downloads*](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) page. JavaFX releases occur on approximately the same cadence as [OpenJDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK).

The `mac` classifier is wrong if it is an M1 Mac. It is better not to supply a classifier unless you know what architecture you are using, and even then, I would avoid it.