# Executable jar file that preloads java

Tags: java

I have a project that I want to be able to run on all computers regardless of whether java is installed or not. I know Minecraft does this by preloading java, and I've looked into programs like exe4j, jsmooth, and launch4j, but have had no luck. Does anyone know how to take my jar file and create an executable that preloads java before running the jar file?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Minecraft does this by preloading java"?  Are you referring to the fact that the Minecraft executable has an embedded JRE?   Also, what version of Java are you using?  Which Java9+ there are new ways of dealing with this kind of problem.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With modern JDKs, you can build native installers without 3rd party installers. [See](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9)

Comment: Link-only answers are usually not good answers, since there is no guarantee the external URL will be valid when future readers visit this page.