# Can I put javafx modules directly into a runnable JAR?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a project that uses Javafx, and my goal is to make a .exe file with Launch4J, because it will be used by other people.
For now, when I export the project in a runnable JAR, if I want to execute it, I have to write as an argument the path of the javafx folder and add the different modules :
`java --module-path javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar test13.05.jar`
Is there a way to put the javafx folder in my projects lib folder, and add the arguments directely into the main function so I can execute the project without having to write the path and add the modules ?

Comment: You can make a desktop shortcut with all jvm arguments as command. Then you just have to click its shortcut

Comment: I could but I want to be able to send the jar via mail to other people, would it be transferred with the file?

Comment: Yes you can if you put all paths relative. I am using ubuntu. I can make an answer  if you want

Comment: There are other aproach by  adding libs in jar and editing its manifest. That will result on just one file

Comment: I think it would help me a lot if you did that. I am using windows and I launch the project from powershell.

Comment: i post it please don't tick as right answer because is not . it's just an idea I give you to solve your issue quickly . there are more elaborated approaches , but need gradle or maven . good luck !

Comment: Instead of distributing a .jar file, you can distribute an [image tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre).

Comment: You might want to look at the info on packaging in the [JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: the idea of packing everything in one file is bad! once you use `launch4j`, set all the options for launching the application in it. when you create the exe file, don't pack everything in it but just create a native launcher (and of course, organize the directory of the application /bin, /lib, /runtime ...).  the last step is to create an installer to distribute the entire application package  as a single installation file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution with a script (linux ubuntu version)**
[image: run script]

Adding jvm arguments as command in .sh script. every path must be relative in order to run it in other linux pc .Nescesary javafx jar are in libs folder

run_demo.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
java --module-path libs --add-modules javafx.controls -jar  demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This aproach can be implemented in other os with their proper scripts

Answer (score 2):

Fat jars are not recommended to distribute JavaFX application for various reasons. Instead use the official [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/index.html) tool to package your application.