# Installing Java on USB Drive without administrator privileges

Tags: java

I am currently writing a `Java` program for a company use.
However, there are no `Java` installed in the company's computer.

Therefore, I would like to know that if it is possible that I can install the Java in the USB (or just together with My Program). Then, if the user install the package of the program that I had written, `Java` will be also being installed.

If it is possible to do that?
(Please assume that the user will mainly use the program in Window platform).

Comment: Have you considered something like a [Java based executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)?  It's unclear that *anything* could be installed on the machine but at least it would be a single .exe to run.

Comment: Can you “embed” the Java Runtime - yes - thus is simply having the JRE binaries and libraries packed with your compiled code and then having a launcher which  can the execute the java command within you package (ie batch file or native executable)

Comment: @stdunbar I had tried to create and .exe file, but it still need Java for running the program, or how can I convert a Java Program to exe which not requires user to run the program without installing Java?

Comment: may be you can  have a reference to ```DOCKER```   , there is  a tech  ```DIND```  could helps you slove your problem

Comment: DIND could package your whole env and application , so that you can run application  skip  env installation step

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre helpful.  (This applies to all Java applications, whether or not they use JavaFX.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement once. I ended up using [jPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) to create a portable Java installation.

When you run the installer, all you need to do is specify an install location (in this case, it would be your USB drive). Once it is installed, you use the `java` executable in the `bin` directory to execute your applications. It works exactly the same way as any other Java installation.