# Automatically install JDK for Windows in a Java program

Tags: java, gradle

I want to add an automatic JDK installation feature to my Java project so that users can get started without having to install the JDK manually. What tools or methods can I use to accomplish this in my project? I am using the Gradle build tool for dependency management.

I can't find a solution anywhere, or anything close to it

Comment: This is not the correct approach.  [Use jlink instead,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453212/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-11-desktop-application-with-a-jre) so users won’t need to install Java at all.

Comment: I need java to be installed on the pc, it is required to run the game.

Comment: No it is not.  Read the link.  jlink will include a stripped-down Java runtime with your program.

Comment: I've read it, but it won't work for me. I just need the client side to make a request to download java and install it if it is missing. Like Idea does.

Comment: What do you mean it won’t work?  Did you try it?  There is a reason jlink exists:  it’s a much better solution than what you’re proposing.  An IDE is not the same as an end user application.

Comment: since you are so much *resisting* to use `jlink` (I don't understand why) have a look at [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) (despite not part of standard Java since version 9)

Comment: I do *not* think this Question deserves closing as a request for software recommendation. This Question is asking about the *concept* behind possibly existing tools. Asking about how to build & bundle Java apps for deployment is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

### Bundle JRE/JDK within app

> users can get started without having to install the JDK manually

You should bundle a JRE/JDK within your app. This is the canonical way to distribute Java desktop apps and console apps. Such apps can qualify for distribution within online app marketplace such as the [*Apple App Store*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(Apple)), [*Google Play*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play), etc.

See [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf) white paper by Oracle, 2020-05.

On a related note, some readers may benefit from reading [*Java Is Still Free*](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nFGazvrCvHMZJgFstlbzoHjpAVwv5DEdnaBr_5pKuHo/edit), written by some pillars of the Java community.

The [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project provides some tooling to enable bundling a JRE/JDK within your app. See:

- [*JEP 282: jlink: The Java Linker*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282)
- [*JEP 392: Packaging Tool*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) (*jpackage*)

Also, on the cutting edge of technology, you may consider building an app of native code using [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM) technology.

### No convenient auto-install

You said:

> I want to add an automatic JDK installation feature to my Java project

As others said, there seems to be no such tool, and no such feature within the Java platform.

In theory, you could write your own to download and install a JVM along the lines of what [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) does. To do that, your app would start by running shell scripts or some native code as there is no way to run Java code without already having a JRE/JDK installed.

#### *OpenWebStart*

You might find happiness with [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com/), an open-source re-implementation of the [*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) technology.

Your [JNLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_(JNLP)) application can be run with a version of Java such as the [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions 8, 11, 17, or 21.

To quote [their FAQ](https://openwebstart.com/docs/FAQ.html):

> Do I have to install a Java on my system to run OWS?
>
> There is no need to have any JVM installed on your system to run OWS. OWS bundles its own JVM. OWS has a JVM Manager which can find local JREs or download JREs (from the Internet) to run your Jnlp application..
>
> Don’t worry if no JVMs are shown in JVM Manager after installation of OWS. If you wish you can use Find local or Add local…​ to detect and add an existing Java instance on your client device to the JVM Manager or simply start the JNLP file and the JVM Manager will download an appropriate JRE for your application.
>
> The downloaded JREs are stored in %userhome%/.cache/icedtea-web/