# JavaFX can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, artifact

I have a JavaFX project that I would like to build as a Jar-file. However, when I attempt to do so, I get an error.

```
Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK
```

I found a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450011/build-and-deploy-javafx-application-using-java11) on here from last year, but it seemed like they concluded nothing.

Comment: First, I downloaded the javaFx sdk from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/, then I created a bat file and I included something like this: java --module-path PATH_TO_JAVAFX_SDK  --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR_FILE

Answer (score 14):

This happens because either you have many JDKs installed and compiling by another and running by another or you are using the Javafx Application jar feature when creating artifacts in Intellij which is unfortunately broken. Before proceeding with the below steps make sure that you are compiling with and running with the same JDK version. 
Here is you fix it:

#### 1 - Create a Launcher class:

The Launcher class is going to call the main JavaFx class from which your appliaction runs. Choosing to make the Jar directly through the Main class is going to error out giving the following error:

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class Main
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

Your Launcher class should look something like this:

```
    public class Launcher {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainGUI.main(args);
        }
    }
```

#### 2 - On to building the Jar

1. You probably still have a `META-INF` folder from the previous build so delete it.
2. Build the project as a JAR:
   [File->Project Structure -> Artifacts -> "+" -> JAR-> from modules with dependancies..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjS8g.png)
3. Choose the Launcher class for you main and check "**copy to the output directory and link via Manifest**" and Press Ok
4. Press Apply then OK.
5. go to Build -> Build artifacts-> Rebuild

Comment: Here is an excellent video explaining the second option:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGHu-SzL-5E&ab_channel=AlexHorea

Comment: I know I'm reviving an old topic (bad practice) but I just wanted to say a huge "Thank you!" because you saved me from pretty much wasting my work on a seemingly unpackage-able program.

Comment: It work! open without adding the modules and no error! thanks

Comment: Нет это не работает.

Answer (score 1):

In the JetBrains website I found a good article about,  [Package JavaFX applications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html)  which was really helpful. In the [#troubleshoot](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html#troubleshoot) section it says that,

> ```
> Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact – fx:deploy is not available in this JDK
> ```
>
> The `fx:deploy` task was a part of the Ant plugin that was formerly
> distributed in `ant-javafx.jar` as a part of Java Packager. The Ant
> plugin is not included in jpackage in the current JDK versions.
>
> If you're using a JDK build of version 9 and later, use third-party
> solutions for packaging. For example, refer to section [Runtime images](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular)
> in the JavaFX official documentation.

Comment: This is a good summary.  Additionally, if somebody is interested in packaging a Java (or JavaFX) application as a native application (e.g. an Windows exe, Linux rpm or deb package, or OS X dmg installed app), then consider using the [jpackage](https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage) utility implemented as an [incubating feature in JDK 14+](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343).  For certain applications, this may provide a better requirements fit than the current options documented for JavaFX [runtime images](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular).

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for mentioning about jpackage. Could you please help me figuring out this; I was trying to create an native executable for a JavaFX modular Maven project. With using [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) I could create a runtime image with a launcher script & then by packaging it with jpackage, I got an bundled exe setup which works fine. But, it installs that launcher script. But what I need is to install running exe file. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Ask a new question Tharindu.  By doing so, multiple people may answer, you will have a better chance of finding someone with the appropriate knowledge to create a good answer for you and there will be a record which somebody can search to get an answer to a similar question.

Comment: Kind of lame that what is supposed to be an IDE cannot even create a final output of a project. I mean, if it only works for Java 8 and below, that is useless in most cases.  I do not understand why IntelliJ did not include a solution (whether their own or a third-party one) for Java 9+. Unless JavaFX is dying or something and IntelliJ practically gave up on it.