# Cannot create JAR-File for JavaFX in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, jar

Cannot find and choose Main-Class creating a JavaFX-Application artefact.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip5EJoF4pDg ...

Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Screenshot 3
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209569). You can type the class name manually as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, but doing so I get another error: 
Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK

Comment: @Mr.T it's a well known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450011/build-and-deploy-javafx-application-using-java11 .

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I still don't understand how my initial problem, to create JavaFX-Jar, can be solved.

Comment: Use Maven or Gradle to build the jars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/javafx-11-create-a-jar-file-with-gradle .

Comment: Tanks a lot! But, I guess that all this is too complex for my small hobby project. It makes no fun any more. But nevertheless tank you very much and I hope that users with a little more proficiency will be able to use your tips more than I am.